# How to remove padding between nav, article, and footer?

Tags: css

Not sure why, but Firefox appears to be adding padding somewhere between `<nav>`, `<article>`, and `<footer>` elements. I tried setting all margins and paddings to zero, no luck so far.

Comment: I suppose you have an `ul` inside your nav?

Comment: Could you show me your code or link?

Answer (score 1):

Derp, twas adding padding to a `<ul>` in the `<nav>`, rather than the `<nav>` itself.